# Quick & easy way to create an "email this page" to someone link?

Tags: php, html

Is there a quick way to create a link that when clicked will allow the user to send the link of the page they're on via mailto?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To send the link of the page you are exactly on try to use the following code:

```
<a HREF="mailto:?subject=look at this website&body=Hi,I found this website
and thought you might like it <?php
$url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
echo $url;
?>">Tell a friend!</a>
```

The php will get the url of the page you are currently on.

Answer (score 3):

Why not using a mailto HTML link?

```
<a href="mailto:?Subject=A%20page%20I%20found%20interesting&body=url_of_your_page">
    Mail this page to a friend
</a>
```

Don't forget to urlencode your subject / body content, for example using [urlencode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) in PHP.